# how to auto select current date or selected date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
forceParse: false,
autoclose: true,
defaultDate: 'now',
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
forceParse: false,
autoclose: true,
startDate: today,
});

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vquj.png)
select date as shown in fingure,

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).